# Android 6.0 Dialog text doesn't appear

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog, android-6.0-marshmallow

I updated my phone to Android 6.0 and I have these 2 problems with dialogs:

1)The title is shown but the messages isn't for alert dialog(SOLVED):

```
        new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setTitle("Title").setMessage("Message");
```

2)Also custom dialog fragment's title is not shown(NOT SOLVED):

```
        getDialog().setTitle("Title");
```

There was not such a problem in lollipop or in older versions, the problem appeared only after updating my phone to marshmallow.

How to solve the problem?

Comment: Post all of your code and you not calling `show`.

Comment: I have edited the code

Comment: where is dialog.show()??

Comment: can give some screenshot because from code only problem we see there is no dialog.show. and provide some more code.

Comment: I have added a screenshot too

Comment: Did you found a solution? I have the same problem message text is white, on white background. I know that solution must be changing the theme for AlertDialog in styles.

Comment: if the answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 41):

Use constructor with theme for Lollipop and newer android versions:

**Dark theme**

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_Alert);
    } else {
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    }
```

And for **Light theme**

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_Dialog_Alert);
    } else {
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Alexandr. This works fine for AlertDialog.Builder case. Is there any way to apply for Custom Dialog (extends Dialog classes and not about Fragments) cases.

Comment: @jettimadhuChowdary, when you create custom dialog use `dialog = new CustomDialog(this,android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_alert);`

Comment: This is not a good approach if you have a lot of dialogs. @Stephen answer is the best one.

Answer (score 31):

I've come across a few answers that say that you should use the following in your app theme:

```
<item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert</item>
```

While that is correct, it wasn't working in all places for me. Eventually, I realized that in some places I was using the regular AlertDialog builder and in other places I was using the support builder. If you are using the support AlertDialog, make sure to also include the following in your theme:

```
<item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert</item>
```

Comment: This answer should be pushed to top.

Answer (score 18):

Just put this in your styles file inside your Base Theme style tag and you are good to go

```
<item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert</item>
```

Comment: I think this solution is better than check and change theme in everywhere that we want to create a `AlertDialog`.

Answer (score 10):

Answer for `2)`, we need to call `setStyle()` before `onCreateDialog()` because `theme` is used in `onCreateDialog()`

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_Dialog_Alert);
    }
    Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    dialog.setTitle(R.string.dialog_title);
    return dialog;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

i tried to fix this problem by making a style of my own.

your dialog object should be like this and your style pointed to this Dialog will be written below

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(Context, R.style.Dialog))
            .setTitle("Title")
            .setMessage("Sample Message ...").show();
```

**R.style.Dialog ::**

```
<style name="Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primary_text</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/primary_color</item>
</style>
```

**Colors ::**

```
<color name="primary_text">#212121</color>
<color name="primary_color">#2196f3</color>
```

finally the output should be something like this

**Note** : "android:textColorPrimary" goes for dialog setMessage and "android:textColor" goes for dialog setTitle ; i do not use setPositive and setNegative button and listener in my dialog object but you can see them in the picture if you want you can make your own dialog object.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
    .setTitle("Delete entry")
    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?")
    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            // continue with delete
        }
     })
    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            // do nothing
        }
     })
    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
     .show();
```

Hope this will help you.............

Comment: it is working for me....OK i will check it one more time and come back to you.....

Comment: is your app's target api 23?

Comment: it is working fine in my application and i have checked it and it is doing fine....... in android api 23 (NEXUS 5 newly updated to android Marshmello)

Comment: title is not getting set in 6.0 ... any clues?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you are ending up showing white text on a white background! (Looking at the screenshot, the (i) icon is not showing up well either, suggesting that it was designed to be shown on a background other than white.

You can use the constructor `public AlertDialog.Builder (Context context, int themeResId)` to ensure you are using a specific theme to style your dialog, where the `Theme_Material_Dialog` is probably what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your main text color is the same as dialog background color, in that case in your styles.xml use (just an example):

```
<style name="AlertDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>
```

and in dialog creation:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(
        new ContextThemeWrapper(getContext(), R.style.AlertDialog))
).setMessage("test");
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `DialogFragment` you need to

1. Add style

   ```
   <style name="CustomDialog" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
       <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
   </style>
   ```
2. In your `DialogFragment` add `getTheme`

   ```
   public class CustomDialogFragment extends DialogFragment{
       public int getTheme() { 
           return R.style.CustomDialogFragment; 
       }
       .
       .
       .
   ```

And that's it!

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_fire_missiles)
               .setPositiveButton(R.string.fire, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       // FIRE ZE MISSILES!
                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       // User cancelled the dialog
                   }
               });
        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return builder.create();
    }
```

Once check this hope this will work.......

Answer (score 0):

In my case all dialogs had the same color as fonts (title & message). What I have done to fix this state was the change of the color attribute in my theme. I copied the xml theme file into the 'res/values-v22' and set different color for marshmallow.

```
<resources>
    <style name="LywCompatTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/tertiary_text_dark</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

or only for dialogs

```
<resources>
    <style name="LywCompatTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/LywAlertDialogStyle</item>
    </style>
    <style name="LywAlertDialogStyle" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/lyw_secondary_text_color</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```