# Blank alertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a weird issue.
I have a simple alertDialog I passed it an arguments but I see it blank except the icon.

this is the method:

```
public class ViewUtil {

//// some code...

public static void showMessagePopup(int titleResId, String message, Context context) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setTitle(context.getResources().getString(titleResId))
            .setMessage(message)
            .setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .show();
}
```

And here I call it

```
public class RedesignNewDriverPopup extends Dialog {
/// some code...

 new PrepareRestApiTask<>(new PrepareRestApiTask.restApiCaller<String>() {
                @Override
                public Call<RestResponse<String>> onRestApiReadyBackgroundRun(String hashedToken,
                                                                              SmartbusClient client) {
                    return client.update_driver(driver.id, req, hashedToken);
                }

                @Override
                public void onEverythingFinishedUIThreadRun(String theData) {
                    updateCallback.afterDriverUpdate();
                    ViewUtil.showMessagePopup(R.string.new_driver, getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.driver_created), getContext());
                    dismiss();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Response<RestResponse<String>> response) {
                    ViewUtil.showMessagePopup(R.string.new_driver, getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.login_error), getContext());
                    dismiss();
                }


            }).execute();
```

this is my theme:

```
 `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowToggle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:tabWidgetStyle">@style/CustomTabWidget</item>
</style>`
```

As I said, I can see the icon but not the title or the message.

Thanks

Comment: use `ActivityName.this` instead of `getContext`

Comment: where? when I call the method? but I am not in an activity
I am in a class that extend Dialog. a kind of popup

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33257083/7320259

Comment: ViewUtil.showMessagePopup(R.string.new_driver, getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.login_error), getContext()); here in place of getContext() Activity.this

Comment: if this doesn't help try to change theme

Comment: Looks like theming issue. Can you post your theme setup?

Comment: Ok. thanks to everyone. I found the problem.
it's the getContext(). 
I passed my context where I create the usage class and use it instead of getContext()
Thanks to all. may I publish my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
ViewUtil.showMessagePopup(activity_context.getResources().getString(R.string.new_driver), activity_context.getResources().getString(R.string.driver_created), activity_context);
```

pass the Activity context in your Dialog class and use it

Also in your :

```
    public static void showMessagePopup(String titleResId, String message, Context context) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setTitle(titleResId)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .show();
}
```

To pass context:

```
//in activity
MyDialogClass dialog=new MyDialogClass(this);
```

Now in your Dialog class use:

```
 Context activity_context;
MyDialogClass(Context context){
this.activity_context=context; //now use activity_context to show alertDialog
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. but I am not in an activity. see my edit
I don't think the context is the problem

Comment: did u try passing a static string "instead" of `getResources.getString()`

Comment: You right. Just edit "MainActivity.this" to "your_passed_context" to be more accurate. and add "your_passed_context" before "getResources().getString(R.string.new_driver)"

Comment: I see. Now it's perfect :)