# Why progress dialogue is not showing title and message on marshmallow?

Tags: android

In my app, I am integrating progress dialogue and I am using below code for creating progress dialogue

```
 public static void showProgressDialogue(final Context context, String title, String mainMessage) {
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setTitle(title);
    progressDialog.setMessage(mainMessage);
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    progressDialog.show();
}
```

And I created 2 emulators one for lollipop and other for marsh mallow. It is showing title and message on lollipop emulator but not showing title and message on marsh mallow emulator. Further  I have tried on real device as well. On marsh mallow (Motorolla droid turbo) device it is not showing title and message. For sake of giving complete understanding i am attaching images as well

[image]

Above images is taken of lollipop emulator

[image]

Above image is taken from marsh mallow emulator

I have googled a lot and could not fine suitable answer that solve my query. Even in one place I found that by changing 'textColorPrimary', it will work. But in my case it did not work. And below is my style.xml code

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/LoyaltyTextView</item>
    <item name="editTextStyle">@style/LoyaltyEditText</item>
</style>
```

Any help?
As requested, I am posting my manifest as well

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".views.activities.SplashActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"></category>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".views.activities.MainActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".views.activities.LoginActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".views.activities.SignUpActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".views.activities.ViewAsGuest"/>
    <activity android:name=".views.activities.BusinessActivity"/>

</application>
```

Comment: did you tried to change parent theme ?

Comment: post ur manifest..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33228454/android-6-0-dialog-text-doesnt-appear/34333092

Comment: @IbrahimBaz yes initially my app theme had action bar and i changed that too NoActionBar. Can it cause any problem? I mean while it is working fine on marsh mallow? Does marsh mallow treats progress bar differently?

Comment: you may change NoActionBar to Dialog

Comment: @IbrahimBaz it is not working man. Even now my activity is being displayed as dialogue

Comment: i mean in your layout.xml chose that style for progressbar and keeb old style for activity.

Comment: @IbrahimBaz, can you please tell me how to acheive that i mean I am not using any custom layout to show progress dialogue.

Comment: If you just want to show progress, a better solution would be to embed a progress bar somewhere in your current layout instead of a dialog