# Title showing 2 times in AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to show an AlertDialog in android. The problem is that the title of the dialog appears 2 times. I want it to show only one title? How can I do it?

That is how the dialog looks like
[image: Dialog showing 2 titles]

And that is how i show the dialog

```
   AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog).create();
                    alertDialog.setTitle(R.string.ttl_alrt_dlg_dont_asked_again);
                    alertDialog.setMessage("AI bifat nu ma mai intreba asa ca mergi in setari");
                    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();


                                    actv.finish();
                                    //ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(actv,
                                      //      new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                        //    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                                }
                            });
                    alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: Does that happen on various devices with various OSes?

Comment: I think its due to this style ``android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its look like its due to `android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog`, First title is `ActionBar` .

**Solutions**

**1.** Just use it without style . It will show in material design appearance anyway .

**2.** Or you can use `android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_NoActionBar`

```
  AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_NoActionBar).create();
  alertDialog.setTitle(R.string.ttl_alrt_dlg_dont_asked_again);
  alertDialog.setMessage("AI bifat nu ma mai intreba asa ca mergi in setari");
  alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
            });
    alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: @Sayem answer is also a good one. But i checked this one as the right answer because it conserves the material appearance.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("title")
            .setMessage("AI bifat nu ma mai intreba asa ca mergi in setari")
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    actv.finish();
                }
            })
            .create();
    alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: your code should work fine. but as it shows duplicate two thing might mess up. one is your theme. another is you are setting title after creating the dialog. so, you can try this.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line-:

```
alertDialog.setTitle(R.string.ttl_alrt_dlg_dont_asked_again);
```

Comment: Then where from would "Permission required" text appear?

Comment: @ShivamOberoi its ``setTitle`` not ``addTitle``. so removing that won't work

Answer (score 0):

It's Theme_Material_Dialog issue. so you have to customize your own dialog by creating style.

see this helpful answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36041424/1856562)

And this complete answer [another_here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29797134/how-to-use-and-style-new-alertdialog-from-appcompat-22-1-and-above)

Answer (score 0):

Faced a similar issue while using AppCompatDialogFragment. Ended up using as below to avoid, title showing up twice:

```
<style name="dialogfrag_title" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:padding">@dimen/lyt_margin</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/appBackground</item>
</style>
```

along with below line in the fragment class.

```
        getDialog().setTitle("About "+ user.name());
```